# What is paid subscription needed for in Mortal Kombat 11?

Tags: mortal-kombat-11

[This recent beta trailer](https://youtu.be/2TQGfkQyMk8?t=66) for upcoming Mortal Kombat 11 has a line in the fine print:

> Paid subscription required for online matchmaking (sold separately).

I don't understand what it means. Which is correct?

1. When you buy the game after its April release, you can play its single-player campaign, but need a separate paid subscription for online competitive play.
2. When you pre-order the game, you are allowed into the beta test, but need an additional paid subscription to compete with others in the beta test.

Comment: I disagree with the current close votes. While the game is not out yet, the question is asking more about online services than the game itself. It is also shown to be answerable

Comment: @Wondercricket Answerability makes for poor criteria for topicality.  I agree the question is asking more about what it means for online play, and that is on-topic.  But just because we *can* answer a question, doesn't automatically mean we *should*.

Comment: Agree with Frank here. This game is not out yet, which means it is off-topic. Pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mortal Kombat 11 is being released for Xbox One, Playstation 4, Nintendo Switch, and PC. If you wish to play multiplayer on any of the consoles (PC excluded, usually) you need to pay for their online subscription services in order to play multiplayer games.

Comment: Has it been confirmed that we'll need Nintendo Switch Online in order to access MK11's multiplayer?

Comment: @senpai Yes, all multiplayer games on Switch are required to have the service, just like the other consoles https://www.nintendo.com/switch/online-service/online-play/ "Nintendo Switch Online membership (sold separately) and Nintendo Account required for online play"

Comment: @Rapitor Fortnite does not - some games do not require this sub.

Comment: @Rapitor Warframe also doesn't require the subscription. There are a bunch of games that don't require Nintendo Switch Online in order to access online capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have either PS+ or Xbox Live Gold to play the online part of the beta. Paid subscription refers to PS+ or Xbox Live Gold, which are sold separately.

> **Is a PlayStation Plus or Xbox Live Gold membership required for the beta?**
>
> A PlayStation Plus subscription or Xbox Live Gold membership is required to participate in online multiplayer matches during the closed beta. These subscriptions are not required to enjoy the Custom Character Variation System or Towers of Time content.

[Source](https://mortalkombatgamessupport.wbgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013188374-Mortal-Kombat-11-Beta-Pre-order-FAQ)